# XML Parsing javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, xml-parsing

I'm using following code to parse the xml file from my local memory in iOS .I have done once the same process correctly but now something wrong happened.

Please check my code.

In that first alert i can see the path of local xml file (/Users/NAVEEN/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/F7E7F34A-93A4-4BFF-B366-E8D39C008C52/Documents/config.xml)

```
alert(configFileUrl);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xhttp.open("GET",configFileUrl,false);
xhttp.send();

newXMLObj=xhttp.responseXML;

alert(newXMLObj);
```

And the bottom alert prints null instead of some Object object value.

Comment: the problem might be in your xml file, are you sure it is a well formatted xml file?

Comment: have you tried to get the `xhttp.responseText`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `xhttp.responseXML` your response must be valid XML content-type `text/xml` or `application/xml`.

Instead of `xhttp.responseXML` you can use `xhttp.responseText` and create XML document in javascript:

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
  var parser=new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText,"text/xml");
}
```

And `ActiveXObject` check is also unnecessary, because there is no ActiveXObject on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are trying to access the xml file with JavaScript on the local filesystem.